# How can I get a user to use script (bound to a Gsheet) to update cell in another Gsheet (user do not have edit access)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Master Sheet with only me having edit access to it. I have another sheet (user sheet) where users can add some data that I want them to update my Master sheet only via a script (in the user sheet). Is this possible? 
I already have the script that can copy data from the user sheet and knows where to paste it in the Master Sheet.

I could do this easily using VBA in excel but I am very new to Gsheet and using Gsheet scripts. Hope someone can help me please.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the user's bound script directly access a Sheet they do not have edit access to.  A bound script always runs [runs with the permissions of the user at the keyboard](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization).

One possible workaround:

You can create a [Google Apps Script web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) that has a [`doPost`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) function that edits your master Sheet.  The web app should be published so that it "runs as you", and has anonymous access (which also means you should be careful how to process the requests you receive).  In the bound script, you can communicate to your web app through [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app), which can send POST requests and give you a response.

Comment: thanks for the response. Since I'm very new to this, not sure what to do, What code should the 'doPost' function have? I am guessing the user facing Gsheet script needs to be published as a webapp. How do i use the UrlFetchApp?POST request. I did a bit of a digging around - not understanding how this works. A sample sheet with codes will really help as I maybe able to modify it to meet my needs. Thanks again.

Comment: What kind of data are you having them add? Maybe what you need is a form that your master sheet  can process, that is a lot easier than a webapp.

Comment: @Rezaur [here is a simple, self-contained example](https://ctrlq.org/code/19871-get-post-requests-google-script).  Your user script would have something like the `testPOST` function, but you'll have to provide the url (if you ran that as written in the bound script, it would just return the url of the bound script - you would need to supply the master web app url).  As the other comments and answers have mentioned, creating a web app solution is not easy and it you are "very new" then you should start small and build up to it.  Consider the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to do this is to have them modify their sheets and then your master sheet reaches out and gets the data from them on a timed trigger. Although making your own webapp would work.

Comment: Thanks. 'on a time trigger' is a good idea but i need the data to be updated real time. Do't have enough knowledge how to make the webapp work. :-(

Comment: Yes, doing webapps is a lot harder than coding in sheets!

Comment: @ J G. I have a gsheet with rosters of my team. I want to remove all editors from it but allow them to edit it only through the user gsheet (another gs). As they select a date and name, the user gs can fetch data from mastersheet (using formula), then 1 of the Team leaders can enter a new start time, click a button for the script to write a row of data to a static row in the user gs, paste the row as a new row in a different tab and then finally just the new value (start time) to the mastersheet respective cell (i can tell which tab/cell the data needs to be added/updated using formula).

Comment: But the user access is my issue here as I dont want the users to have edit access to the mastersheet. :-)

Using Forms as you suggested would be good but dont know how to use data validation in the forms, also the user need to be able to see the current roster data in the form - is that easy to do?
If you have any other solution for this set up I would appreciate it. I have done many similar thing in the past, but using VBA and excel which worked pretty well. But gsheet is new for me and I dont know much coding.

Comment: So it looks like what you really want is a form with a dropdown populated with your employees and a date field and a time field?